# How to sign .txt or .pdf file using signtool.exe

Tags: winforms

I  am able to sign PE file such as .msi, .exe .dll but In my project there is requirement to sign .pdf file .txt file means non PE files. can anyone please let me know how to sign non PE(portable executable) such as .txt, .pdf, .png, etc. files using signtool.exe ?

Comment: `So you want to make sure that nobody changed the contents of the text file, that's the point isn't it?
A rough outline of a possible solution:
Read the text of the file, apply a hash function, encrypt the hash using your private key of a non-symmetric encryption function. Add a new line containing the encrypted hash value (encoded in BASE64 or something textual).
When you want to check the contents, read the file, use the same hash function and compare the result with the de-cryption of the stored hash value.`

Comment: Thanks for you quick reply.

Your approach is valid.

But I want to ask you if is there any way to sign non PE files using signtool.exe itself ?

Comment: Is there any API which can do signing using cross certificate in Windows ?

Answer (score 1):

Just rename your file to *.js and use signtool (example with maXbox shell):

```
     TOSIGNFILE:= 'result34to2.js'; //'result34to2.txt'; 

     if fileExists(CERTFILE) then begin
       writeln(botostr(ChDirW(TOOLPATH)));
       passfromfile:= FileToString('./certs/passfile2.txt')
       ExecuteShell('signtool.exe', 'sign /f'
         +' certs/maxbox4exe.pfx /p '+passfromfile
         +' /t http://timestamp.digicert.com '+TOSIGNFILE);
```

Comment: Works fine and rename to *.txt afterwards

Answer (score 1):

In maXbox you can use GetDOSOutput to see commandline messages:

```
 writeln(GETDOSOutput('signtool.exe sign /f'
                     +' certs/maxbox4exe.pfx /p '+passfromfile
                     +' /t http://timestamp.digicert.com '+TOSIGNFILE
                                                          ,TOOLPATH));
```

> > TRUE
> > Done Adding Additional Store
> > Successfully signed: result34to2.js

And, Or verify the sign and stamped file:

```
 WinExec32('cmd /C signtool.exe verify /v /pa '+TOSIGNFILE+' > signresult34.txt',1);
 openFile(TOOLPATH+ 'signresult34.txt');
```

Answer (score 0):

Encapsulate your txt file into a cab file or an empty "dll" (PE) file. then you can easy sign with signtool, (or any one can do it) and there are plenty of ways or OS api (user or kernel) to check the pe or cab integrity-trust. Using a PE and the windows os resource load-update api will help you. BTW, PE is easier to handle than cab...